# How to represent system constants in XAML (like double.MaxValue)

Tags: xaml, constants

What is the **xaml** equivalent of `MyProperty = double.MaxValue`?
I'm afraid I'll need to use something like `MyProperty="{x:Static sys:Int32.MaxValue}"`, but not sure, and can't find the equivalent for double. Thanks.

Answer (score 45):

Found:

add this in the namespaces section of the control to access System library:

```
... xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" ...
```

then, to set Maximum property of MyControl control in ctr namespace:

```
<ctr:MyControl Maximum="{x:Static sys:Double.MaxValue}"/>
```

Edit:

```
{x:Static sys:Double.PositiveInfinity}
```

works too, but I suspect it is not appropriate to use it in this context, it seems to be reserved for evaluation like `if (x==Double.PositiveInfinity)`. Experts can elaborate...

Answer (score 5):

```
{x:Static sys:Double.PositiveInfinity}
```

could be useful in case you have say some control setting `MaxWidth` to some value and you want to reset it via XAML at some ancestor

This is because `double.PositiveInfinity is the default value (not set) for`MaxWidth`/`MaxHeight`.

I found this useful with Silverlight Media Framework to hide/show the video area (to just hear the audio). See relevant notes near the bottom of:

[How to hide the video area of the Silverlight media framework player](http://zoomicon.wordpress.com/2012/10/03/howto-hide-video-area-of-silverlight-media-framework-player/)